# renaming file prefixes and filetypes

Tags: python, scripting, rename

In python 2.7, how would I go about renaming any `.bat` files in my current directory to a file called `1.txt`?
(ex) If these are the files in my directory: `[test.txt, abc.exe, dkckx.bat, 123.vbs]`, how could I rename the `dkckx.bat` to `1.txt`?
thx in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Check the python documentation for the [`rename`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.rename) function.

And may be [`glob`](http://docs.python.org/library/glob.html#glob.glob) will be helpful too.

Answer (score 0):

[`os.path`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html) has everything you'd need for filename manipulation. [`glob`](http://docs.python.org/library/glob.html) can search for files:

```
import os, glob

i = 1

for f in glob.glob('*'):
  if os.path.splitext(os.path.split(f)[-1])[-1].lower() == '.bat':
    os.rename(f, '{0}.txt'.format(i)
    i += 1
```

No guarantees, but I think this above script should work.